# App crashing after parsing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I get data from a request that has the next structure:

- description
- idd
- name
- url
- photo

"result" from the NSDictionary stores info, this is the method I use.

```
-(void)loadLinks{

    NSDictionary *dictToSend = @{@"controller": @"link",
                                 @"action": @"loadall"
                                 };

    [ApiCaller sendDictionary: dictToSend
                        toURL: nil
                      withKey: nil
            completionHandler: ^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {

                    [CommonFunctions desActivateIndicator];

                    DCArrayMapping *mapper = [DCArrayMapping mapperForClassElements:[JSONLink class] forAttribute:@"data" onClass:[JSONLinks class]];

                    DCParserConfiguration *config = [DCParserConfiguration configuration];
                    [config addArrayMapper:mapper];

                    DCKeyValueObjectMapping *parser = [DCKeyValueObjectMapping mapperForClass:[JSONLinks class]  andConfiguration:config];

                    linksData = [parser parseDictionary: result];

                    [tableview reloadData];
                }
            }];
}
```

I'm using this to fill a tableview with some links. The error is the next.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<JSONLink 0x7fc7f0c759b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'
```

My ***JSONLinks.h*** file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface JSONLinks : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *success;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;

@end
```

My ***JSONLink.h*** file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface JSONLink : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *idd;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *descriptionData;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *photo;

-(NSString *) urlDirection;

@end
```

Where is the error? :S

Thank you.

Comment: Your error show that you set value with 'description' key.I guess that you should map it to `descriptionData ` key,not `description`

Comment: I've just changed *descriptionData; to description, with the same error.

Comment: Try avoiding "description" as key as this is "reserved" for debugging.. find a workarround or ask to change the structure of recived data